# Transparent <hr> for responsive vertical spacing: is it really that unsemantic?

Tags: html, css, frontend, semantic-markup

I have started using a technique for handling vertical spacing in front-end design that uses transparent `<hr>` for spacing elements. I know this owes me the hate of the majority of the web community, but I still think it's a great way to handle special cases. Here are the benefits:

1. `<hr>` is a self-closing tag, so it is kind on the markup
2. Its very semantic purpose (according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/hr)) is to *represent a thematic break* or a *shift of topic with a section*. MDN also precises that it *is now defined in semantic terms, rather than presentational terms*, which mean that an invisible `<hr>` that only takes space does not oppose the semantic meaning of the element.
3. It is easy to consistently style across browsers
4. We can build responsive behaviour right into it

I am very much aware of the needed separation between markup and style. However, vertical spacing between elements in responsive design is sometimes tedious to do, and often comes with a higher price than semantic markup in my opinion.

A common approach is to handle special cases with manual styling: when component-based classes such as `.my-special-recurring-element` is not precise enough (let's say this particular one is too close to the element below it), well add an id `#special-element-that-requires-spacing` and style it manually, which becomes very hard to maintain:

```
/* Ensure that the special element is not too close to the footer in mobile */

#special-element-that-requires-spacing {
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  #special-element-that-requires-spacing {
    margin-bottom: 0;
  }
}
```

This is why CSS utility toolkits such as [Tachyons](http://tachyons.io/docs/) and [Basscss](http://basscss.com/) have became more popular in the recent years. It allows tweaking vertical spacing with inline classes, with the added benefits of direct responsiveness handling. We can now write our HTML like this (example in Tachyons):

```
<div class="my-special-recurring-element mb1 mb0-ns"></div>
```

where `.mb1` roughly means *apply a margin-bottom of 1 on our size scale* and `mb0-ns` means *apply a margin-bottom of zero in non-small viewport width*. This is definitely more practical for front-end design, but it often becomes a cluttered mess that - in my opinion - defies the markup-styling separation more than anything. Using such toolkits, we often end up with markup like this:

```
<div class="ph2 pv3 pv2-m pv1-l mb2 mb2-ns"></div>
```

So what we're doing here is practical and quick, but unmaintainable. It also doesn't help us with a very common use case: *“Where do I put the space? Do I add a `padding-bottom` to this? A `margin-top` to this? Oh, I need to remove the padding here on mobile, but the margin here on non-small”*, etc., etc.

Enter the `<hr>` space. We can now put a single `<hr class="space-1">` between the two elements we want to separate, and have consistant, readable, maintainable and semantic spacing between elements that clutters neither the markup nor the stylesheet.

```
hr.space-1 {
  background: transparent;
  color: transparent;
  margin: 0;
  height: 1rem;
}

@media screen and (min-width: 640px) {
  hr.space-1 {
    height: 1.5rem;
  }
}

@media screen and (min-width: 1200px) {
  hr.space-1 {
    height: 2rem;
  }
}
```

Is it really that much of a crime? What are the drawbacks you see with this approach?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not a crime at all.  I'd do it with a div and a class, but you're right, it's more "semantically proper" with a <hr>.  There was a tag called <spacer> and it served exactly this purpose; my only problem with <hr> is that it can only add *vertical* space, it's not really useful for horizontal situations.  But that's a rare case anyway.

HTML5 is still not perfect for *totally and absolutely semantic* markup; there are tags with dashes that could solve this problem but:

http://caniuse.com/#search=custom

...they're not really supported.  Not yet.  However beautiful a <vertical-space> tag would be, you just can't do it right now.

So don't be scared of using some not-so-semantic markup in your code; it will evolve soon as HTML5 support increases.  And don't listen to the standard-or-die kind of freaks.  They are in a temporary state of learning.

Answer (score 5):

To use `hr` in a semantic way means to use it according to its definition. HTML 5.1 [defines](https://www.w3.org/TR/2016/REC-html51-20161101/grouping-content.html#the-hr-element):

> The `hr` element represents a paragraph-level thematic break, e.g., a scene change in a story, or a transition to another topic within a section of a reference book.

You may style the `hr` element in any way you like (which includes making it transparent), it doesn’t affect its meaning. But you must only use it for *thematic breaks*.

Don’t use `hr` because you need vertical space.
Use `hr` because you have a thematic break (which you may visually represent with vertical space).

Any other use is, by definition, not semantic.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a crime? No. It's a valid HTML/CSS.

**But**

It is semantically incorrect. `hr` implies (for most web developers) that some visual element should appear. If you only use it as a spacer, then use a `div` instead. It's transparent by default opposed to the `hr` and it will be easier to maintain by others.

I even prefer using a `br` with a class rather than `hr` to space elements.

Don't underestimate the fact that most developers don't share your opinion. To emphasize it, imagine using a design pattern to solve a different problem than it always used to. It will confuse others, when trying to understand what problem you tried to solve.

Comment: I get your point, but the sole fact that it requires closing `</div>` implies to me that there could be content inside, which defeats the purpose of a spacer, so I think a self-closing tag such as  `<hr>` is actually easier to maintain by others. Thanks though!

Comment: Yes, you explained why you think it's better, but, 99.99% of the developers doesn't share your opinion. If you're looking for approval to use it, then go a head, but be sure that if you're doing something non conventional, it will make your code less readable.

Comment: <br> is a good idea; something like that is what I'd gladly use too. But sticking to the most precise definitions instead of using a language is the wrong way to go. Feel free to use elegant solutions. Anyone who doesn't understand the meaning of a transparent hr (or a br with display:block) should not touch a keyboard. Be consistent, be understandable, but use your freedom when coding - otherwise you'll hate it after a while.